# THEOS compiling error on simple tweak

Tags: ios, cydia, theos

I've been using Flex to create patches for iOS 7 and decided I'd try creating a dedicated Cydia Tweak. Starting off simple I decided to update a tweak for no icon badges for iOS 7.

My Tweak.xm file looks like this

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

%hook SBIconController
- (BOOL) iconViewDisplaysBadges:(id) {
    return FALSE; }
%end
```

The Makefile for this project is

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = NoIconBadgesiOS7
NoIconBadgesiOS7_FILES = Tweak.xm
NoIconBadgesiOS7_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
    install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

I know I'm hooking the right thing and the right method since it works with Flex, just not sure what I'm doing wrong since it fails during compile.

The errors are:

- Only constructors take base initializers
- anarchistic old-style base class initializer

Error 1 and Error 2

Comment: Show the `Makefile`, and make sure your copy of THEOS is up-to-date

Comment: Updated it with the Makefile, THEOS is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being I wasn't using the correct method as shown in the headers file. Added arg1 at the end.